# Apple connection issues

Tags: connection

My internet connection on my Mac always disconnects from the internet every 5-10 minutes. I have considered that I'm too far away from the router, but this is the first day it's starting to do this. I've only had this laptop since December of 2014. I'm getting really tired of this. If you can help me, that would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Did you upgrade the operating system (OS) recently? I've read a number of reports of people experiencing such problems after an OS upgrade. E.g., from the [MacRumors](http://www.macrumors.com/) article [Some OS X Yosemite Users Plagued With Wi-Fi Connection Issues](http://www.macrumors.com/2014/10/30/yosemite-wi-fi-connection-issues/).

> The problems appear to be affecting a wide range of different MacBooks, different routers, and users in different locations. A number of different fixes have been suggested on various forums, but it does not appear that any one solution works for everyone, suggesting there may be an issue with Yosemite that needs to be addressed in a future update.
>
> Some users have had luck disabling Bluetooth, turning off Handoff, creating new Network Locations, doing a clean Yosemite install, setting a router to "G-mode only," turning off Dropbox syncing, disabling WPA router encryption, or turning off all proxies in Network preferences, but other users have not been able to solve their Wi-Fi problems at all even attempting all of the above listed solutions. Swapping to a 2.4GHz band has, however, worked for a large number of users.
>
> Apple support representatives have supplied users with different solutions that have included removing excess preferred networks in the Network section of System Preferences and resetting the System Management Controller.

If you move the laptop closer to the router, does the problem go away? Have you placed anything near the router recently that could interfere with the signal, [such as laundry detergent or cat litter](http://www.edn.com/electronics-blogs/brians-brain/4438574/Laundry-detergent--cat-litter--and-Wi-Fi-)?

Have you tried running the [OS X Wireless Diagnostics](http://support.moonpoint.com/os/os-x/wireless/diagnostics.php)? At the bottom of the display you see when you hold down the `Option` key while clicking on the icon for wireless networking at the top of the screen you will see "Open Wireless Diagnostics"; select that option to start the wireless networking diagnostics program provided by Apple.